# Jquery Ajax Form from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did a jQuery form (form1) which bring another form(form2) in that page through ajax.
Now I want to submit the form2 data through ajax.

But whenever I click the button, it submit the whole page. I mean the whole page reloads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form2").submit(function() {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    beforeSubmit: function(before) {
                        $('.loading_result').html('Loading...');
                    },
                    success: function(dd) {
                        $('.loading_result').html(dd);
                    }
            }); 
            return false;
        });

    });
```

All the JavaScript codes in the parent page. I don't have any JavaScript codes in ajax pages

//

page.php
* There is a form (form1) in this page.
* All the jQuery functions are inside the page.php

When the form1 is submitted, it brings data from page2.php // It works good.
** page2.php gives form2.

Now when i submit the from2 (which is also in page.php after the ajax request) it does not trigger the jquery function inside page.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding the form submit on `$(document).ready`, I usually just include an "onclick" event to the form's button:

```
<button type='submit' onclick='MyAjaxFunction();return false;'>Submit</button>
```

The `return false;` portion of the onclick will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: with this method, how do i get the form's post data?

Comment: Thanks. I used $.ajax with data serialize :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the form is being submitted in the traditional sense. This is the default action of the submit event. You need to suppress this:

```
$("#form2").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //<-- prevent the event's default action
    //code here...
```

Comment: Nope. It still loads the page

Comment: Well that is definitely how to suppress a submit event - [here's the proof](http://jsfiddle.net/4wDJj/). Perhaps you're targeting the wrong selector or didn't quite implement the code I posted. See the JS Fiddle.

Comment: $("#form2").submit(function() { this line is inside document.ready ==> When the page loads, there is no form with id "form2". Could it be a problem?

Comment: Well the only thing I can think, then (without seeing a JSFiddle of your situation) is you `$("#form2").submit(...` line is running before form 2 is actually inserted into the page. This would mean the event callback never fires, because, as the time it was set, the element (`#form2`) was not in the DOM. If this is the case, you would need to bind the event when it IS inserted into the DOM, not on DOM ready. I can't really advise any more without seeing a Fiddle.

Comment: But `return false` does pretty much the same (blocks the submit) when it comes to form submission.

Comment: Can you tell me how to bind the event? Because #form2 does not exist while the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @techfoobar - I didn't spot the return, good point. Seems this is not about default action prevention, but good old DOM issues. Kamini - you need to move your current event binding line (`$('#form2').submit(...`) to occur at the point when form 2 is inserted into the page. You didn't post the code behind that, so I can't show it. Is it being loaded over AJAX? In that case, do it in the success callback to your AJAX.